# Python GUI tkinter NameError

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im new here, and i have a problem on a quiz im working with Python Tkinter.

So here is the code:

```
b5 = Button(root, text="Next Question",command=question_2_output)
b5.configure(command = des)
b5.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

With this button im trying to acess on two functions. -->

```
def question_2_output():

    lab7 = Label(root, text="Qestion 2 Qestion 2 Qestion 2 Qestion 2", 
    font="Verdana 11 italic")
    lab7.pack()
    lab7.place(x = 350, y = 60)


def des():
    q1.destroy()
```

With this code i try to put lab7 on the same place the previous Question q1 were and destroy/delete  the older Label (Question). But i get this error NameError: name 'q1' is not defined. I cant destroy q1. q1 is in this function.

```
def question_1_output():
    q1 = Label(root, text="This is a very very very very very long question?", font="Verdana 11 italic")
    q1.pack()
    q1.place(x = 350, y = 60)
```

Any help?? Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the other problems that have been noted: you can't use both `.pack()` and `.place()` on the same widget, and you can't set the `command=` option of a Button to two different functions.  In both cases the second will overwrite the first.

Comment: In this situation I would likely use the same label and just update the label with new information using `label_name.config(text="New question")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better off just updated the label instead of destroying it and adding a new one.

I would also use a class to build this GUI as it will be easier to use class attributes and cleaner to read. Avoiding the use of `global` is a good practice and we can do this with class attributes.

Here is a simple example of how you can go about updating the label and button.

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent=parent
        self.question_label = tk.Label(self, text="Question 1", font="Verdana 11 italic")
        self.question_label.pack()
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Next Question",command=self.question_2_output)
        self.b1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def question_1_output(self):
        self.question_label.config(text="Question 1")
        self.b1.configure(text="Next Question", command=self.question_2_output)

    def question_2_output(self):
        self.question_label.config(text="Question 2")
        self.b1.configure(text="Previous Question", command=self.question_1_output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    GUI(root).pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why updating and not destroying?

Comment: @StavriusMtvs It's a situational choice. You might wish to destroy and recreate a frame if each new frame is different from the previous one. But in this case all the content is basically the same so updating the frame seams more efficient to me.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a `global variable q1` in your `question_1_output()` function and `des()` function

```
def des():
    global q1
    q1.destroy()


def question_1_output():
    global q1
    q1 = Label(root, text="This is a very very very very very long question?", font="Verdana 11 italic")
    q1.pack()
```

And to let you `button` execute two function you can do it this way

```
b5 = Button(root, text="Next Question", command=lambda:[des(), question_2_output()])
b5.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Answer (score 0):

`q1` is in the local scope of the function `question_1_output` and thus not visible in the function `des`.

Reorder the definitions or return the object from the function, like this:

```
def question_1_output():
    q1 = Label(root, text="This is a very very very very very long question?", font="Verdana 11 italic")
    q1.pack()
    q1.place(x = 350, y = 60)
    return q1

def des(question):
    question.destroy()

q1 = question_1_output()
des(q1)
```

Though I don't see the point of the function `des` if it merely calls `destroy` on the object.